# showing overlay over bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

i want to display overlay over my bootstrap modal while i am fetching data from server for my paging request. but problem is the overflow container of Modal. i want to display overlay only on modal body area. but that over-flow make my overlay div to act like `position:fixed` instead of `position:absolute`.

here is the fiddle [Fiddle overlay Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CYG6v/)

click save changes on modal to show overlay.

Please help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are adding overlay to `<body>` of page instead add overlay inside the "#myModal" div, then it will start to act like position absolute element. You then just have to change some styling to fit it properly on modal box.

Comment: Great, that works... can you please guide me why adding in body not helping it?

Comment: Thats because if you want two position absolute elements work with each other then you should add them in same parent, which have position relative. It didn't work previously because modal div was in "#myModal" container & overlay in body.